# MySQL replication sometimes lags

Tags: mysql, delay, replication, synchronization, lag

I have a master-slave replication setup that sometimes lags and sometimes doesn't.

I just ran a test with a simple update on a single row, and the slave picked it up immediately, but on a second run, it took more than 15 minutes to replicate.

This has been happening for a few weeks now, and I can't figure out why.
No updates, no changes, but the 2 servers do run different versions of MySQL (all > 5 though).

I have checked the slave status, and everything is fine over there. No seconds behind master, status is 'Waiting for master to send event'. No network issues also, because I ran the second test over and over again repeatedly and it wouldn't have worked if there were any network issues.

Any clues? Thanks!

PS: When it starts lagging, if I stop the slave and start it back up, the lag goes away and the changes come through immediately to the slave. Weird, right?

Comment: I kept checking the slave for the updated record until the new values showed up. The master has hardly any queries running, most of the time, so no. Not a chance of being overwhelmed or anything like that..

Comment: It just happened again, and I was in no mood to wait 15 minutes to see if the changes propagate to the slave, so I just stopped the slave and started it back up and the changes instantly came through.

Comment: Different networks, dedicated IP addresses. Using actual IP address. No GTID (have no idea what that is, but I don't think so..).

Comment: Maybe this is relevant, so just in case, I'll say it: The master machine is shut down during the night (it's actually a laptop running XAMPP). Is it possible that because the slave can't connect to it during the night, it won't try to connect very often during the day?

Comment: Well maybe...remember that replication is asynchronous, meaning that the statement does not execute right away. so if you shut down your master (why you do that I don't know, especially without stopping the slave) then it is possible that the slave gets `n` seconds behind master..Next time run `show slave status\G` on the slave and look for `Seconds behind master`, if that is a very high number that would explain the "lag" that you speak of...

Comment: The master is a laptop which isn't used during the night and has to be stored away and locked (it can't be left running in the drawer).
But what I am talking about here is lag during the day, when it is always running. So, one minute there is no lag, and half an hour later, lag! And then no lag again, half an hour later.

Comment: Seconds behind master is always 0. It is the master log file and position that is behind, I have checked.. It looks very likely to be a network issue. I am thinking about ugrading the slave to version 5.5 and see if the new hearbeat thing fixes it (master is 5.6 and slave is 5.1 right now)...